# as3 addChild into a generated triangle

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Helly everyone! I'm trying to dynamically add (and later remove) some movieclips inside of a triangle. Simple movieclip inside of a movieclip ain't working (it's a square in the end). Drawing a triangle is simple, addChild method is crystal clear too. The tough part comes after. Here's the code I'm trying to develop:

```
btn_toys_2.confirm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, confirmToys);
import flash.display.Graphics;

var point1:Point = new Point(466, 65);
var point2:Point = new Point(370, 540);
var point3:Point = new Point(570, 540);

var vertices:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, point3.x, point3.y]);

var triangle:Sprite = new Sprite();

triangle.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
triangle.graphics.drawTriangles(vertices);
triangle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(triangle);

function confirmToys(e:MouseEvent){
    var toy:MovieClip = new shar_001;
    triangle.addChild(toy);
    toy.x = Math.random()*30;
    toy.y = Math.random()*30;
}
```

The "toy" movieclip is for some reason placed outside the triangle (0-30 x axis and 0-30 y axis).
The important part is to make "toys" appear within a triangle, doesnt have to be a movieclip. A way around this would be great too!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you verify that the shar_001 object has a normal anchor point? Either centered or top left.

Comment: Where does the toy appear exactly? Remove the random component and then trace toy.x and trace triangle.x and let me know what happens

Comment: Removing the random, traces zeros for both x and y. And its for both "toys" and "triangle" (for some reason?). And its anchor point is top left.

Comment: Oh and it appears in upper-left corner of the stage.

Comment: Ok. I can answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if a position is within the desired boundaries and rejecting it if it's not is certainly a solution. However, this stops the program from being deterministic, because you never know how many tries it takes before a position within the boundaries is found.

Does that mean the program could run forever? Possibly yes, but this is so unlikely that it's not going to happen. Depending on how much of its bounding box a triangle fills, it will still produce quite a few misses though. Misses that have to be checked, rejected and tried again.

I'm not advising against this strategy because it might be a performance problem (and it might actually be one), but rather because it seems to miss the point: if positions in a triangle should be found, let's just do exactly that. All this trial and error and testing and rejecting is counterintuitive.

---

You only have one pseudo random number generator built in: `Math.random()`.
That produces an **evenly distributed** random number between 0 and 1. (let's ignore whether the boundaries are possible values or not)

To create a 2D distribution, it's very easy to simply use two of those.

Now the problem with the even distribution is that it's even. To form a non-rectangular shape, transformations have to be applied.

Consider two edges of the triangle to be two vectors. A random point in the triangle is found by combining those two vectors linearly in a random way.

Obviously, with the untransformed random numbers, that would yield a diamond shaped boundary for the random points. To compensate for the fact that the vectors meet at one point and diverge in the other direction the square root is applied to one random number. The math behind that is not too complicated but ain't trivial either. I choose to omit it here. For more information ask a new question, math.se is probably a good place to do this.

Here's a full fledged example code to be used as a document class, which puts 1000 circles into a triangle boundary:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main() 
        {
            var distribution:EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary = new EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary(new Point(100, 100), new Point(400, 50), new Point(250, 350));

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            {
                // create an object in each iteration of the loop
                var circle:Shape = new Shape();

                //add some graphics (this is unnecessary if you use a library symbol)
                circle.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, .6);
                circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 3);
                circle.graphics.endFill();

                // add it to the display list
                addChild(circle);

                // reposition it with the help of the distribution object
                distribution.positionDisplayObject(circle);
            }
        }
    }
}

import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import flash.geom.Point;

internal class EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary
{
    private var u:Point;
    private var v:Point;
    private var position:Point;

    public function EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary(a:Point, b:Point, c:Point)
    {
        // consider corner "a" as the position of the triangle, this is arbitrary decision, but has to be consistent with the rest of this constructor
        position = a;

        // create two vectors from the corner that is the position to the other two corners respectively
        u = b.subtract(a);
        v = c.subtract(a);
    }

    public function getRandomPosition():Point
    {
        // random position formula with two random variables: position + (u + (v-u) * random1) * sqrt(random2)

        var r1:Number = Math.random();

        // the sqrt transforms the probability density function of the even distribution f(x) = 1 into a triangle g(y) = 2y
        var r2:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.random());

        // applying the above formula to create an evenly distributed random position within the triangle
        return position.add(new Point((u.x + (v.x - u.x) * r1) * r2, (u.y + (v.y - u.y) * r1) * r2));
    }

    // convenience function to position a display object at a random position in the triangle
    public function positionDisplayObject(object:DisplayObject):void
    {
        var position:Point = getRandomPosition();

        object.x = position.x;
        object.y = position.y;
    }
}
```

Creating the random distribution is a class of its own. For the sake of simple testing, it's an internal class, thus the entire example is a single class that goes into a single file. Of course, in production code, this should be better organised.

Here are 4 results that I got:

[image: 4 results]

---

> it seems I need to transfer all of my frames/timeline code (and there's a lot!) into the external class

That isn't necessary although it is recommended. You should eventually only use class based code, but of course making that transition within a project isn't very practical.

In my example above, there are two classes: `Main` and `EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary`. You are only interested in the latter one. `Main` is just there to use the other class, create and display the circles, etc: it's a demo.

To use `EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary` in your project, create a new text file in the same directory as your .fla file named `EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary.as` with the following content:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary
    {
        private var u:Point;
        private var v:Point;
        private var position:Point;

        public function EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary(a:Point, b:Point, c:Point)
        {
            position = a;

            u = b.subtract(a);
            v = c.subtract(a);
        }

        public function getRandomPosition():Point
        {
            var r1:Number = Math.random();
            var r2:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.random());

            return position.add(new Point((u.x + (v.x - u.x) * r1) * r2, (u.y + (v.y - u.y) * r1) * r2));
        }

        public function positionDisplayObject(object:DisplayObject):void
        {
            var position:Point = getRandomPosition();

            object.x = position.x;
            object.y = position.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use that class like any other class in your project. For example, you can add the code from `Main`'s constructor to your timeline and it should work:

```
var distribution:EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary = new EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary(new Point(100, 100), new Point(400, 50), new Point(250, 350));

for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    // create an object in each iteration of the loop
    var circle:Shape = new Shape();

    //add some graphics (this is unnecessary if you use a library symbol)
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, .6);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 3);
    circle.graphics.endFill();

    // add it to the display list
    addChild(circle);

    // reposition it with the help of the distribution object
    distribution.positionDisplayObject(circle);
}
```

You should see a triangle of red circles similar to those I posted in the image of results above. Does that work?

Comment: That's a sweet solution You came up with, and I'd love it... but now I've got this error: "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript". Googled it and it seems I need to transfer all of my frames/timeline code (and there's a lot!) into the external class, or the other way round. Basically I'd need to rewrite most of my scripting anew, and before doing so, I'd like to ask is there a way to go around it? Leave the .as file and the I've used so far?

Comment: @SimeonSergeev I guess you are new to class based code and my example code was probably a little overwhelming and confusing given that it contained two classes. I edited my answer to show how you can use my code without changing the rest of your project.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Gives me error 1046 & 1180. I - btw - did manage to use my stack of rects, from another question (thanks to ur answer!). Now i'm trying to position my "toys" within the boundaries of each rectangle. But I still feel like trying both ways.

Comment: @SimeonSergeev What lines do you get these errors on?

Comment: This:
var distribution:EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary = new EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary(new Point(100, 100), new Point(400, 50), new Point(250, 350));

Comment: @SimeonSergeev you need to import the class, try `import EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary`, sorry for this guesswork, I have no IDE or compiler for As3 at hand at the moment.

Comment: Error 1172 Definition Could Not Be Found. got the feeling im doing something wrong here

Comment: @SimeonSergeev make sure you saved the class file next to your .fla file (in the same directory). If it'S there, your classpath is not setup. to do thsi go to File -> Publish settings, near Script : Actionscript 3, click the Actionscript settings icon. (or in general find your Actionscript settings), there should be a list that you can modify and one of its entries should be "." for current file directory. If it's not there, please add it.

Comment: Error 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method addFrameScript. It didnt work before beause I removed the class file. Added back and got this.

Comment: @SimeonSergeev did you modify your Document class? Did you set my class as the document class? The error message suggests that you did exactly that. You shouldn't do that. The class I provided is not intended to be a document class. As I said, you can ignore the `Main` class. It is not of interest to you as it's just a demo. If you want to see the same behaviour on your timeline, add the code snippet to your timeline as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Placed Your snippet in a new .fla, and... got these errors: 1172, 1046, 1180. It just doesnt like the "EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary" thing. Used Your document class file, and it worked just fine. Tho I didn't manage to implement it in my project.

Comment: @SimeonSergeev as you do not seem to have a global Actionscript classpath setup, a new .fla file will not work unless you also copy the `EvenDistribution2DTriangleBoundary.as` file into the same directory and modify the actionscript settings that the current path is considered a classpath (as described earlier: the single dot character should be present as a class path directory). Then you should be able to use my snippet on the main timeline.

Comment: Sorry it took so much time to revise my choice of the correct answer :) I'm finally managing (bit by bit) to use Your solution the way I want to! Adding some dynamic points, controlling the number of circles, the type of circles etc etc. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

It is happening this way because you have made your triangles anchor point at zero. You did this when you did

```
addChild(triangle);
```

That will always put the added child at (0,0).  The only reason you triangle doesn't appear there is because you have added a cushion of empty pixels by making your `point`s be greater than zero.  Instead, you will use

```
addChild(triangle);
triangle.x = 370;
triangle.y = 65;
```

The point you want the top left corner of your triangle to be at is (370, 65).  You should make your triangle points be (96, 0), (0, 475), (200, 475).  Now the top left corner of the triangle is at (0,0) on the stage. Now set the triangle to (370, 65) after adding the triangle to the stage. Now the triangles anchor point is still the top left corner of the triangle, not the stage, so when you add the toy, it will be in reference to the point you expect.

```
// let the minimum x and y be zero, and adjust the others relative to that.
var point1:Point = new Point(96, 0);
var point2:Point = new Point(0, 475);
var point3:Point = new Point(200, 475);
var toyArray:Array = new Array();

var vertices:Vector.<Number> = Vector.<Number>([point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, point3.x, point3.y]);

var triangle:Sprite = new Sprite();

triangle.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
triangle.graphics.drawTriangles(vertices);
triangle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(triangle);
// position anchor point on stage
triangle.x = 370;
triangle.y = 65;


function confirmToys(e:MouseEvent){
    var p:Point = new Point(Math.random()*triangle.width,Math.random()*triangle.height);
    if (isInsideTriangle(Point1,Point2,Point3,p))
        {
            var toy:MovieClip = new shar_001;
            triangle.addChild(toy);
            toyArray.push(toy);
            toy.x = p.x;
            toy.y = p.y;
        }
    }

private function isInsideTriangle(A:Point,B:Point,C:Point,P:Point):Boolean {
        var planeAB:Number = (A.x-P.x)*(B.y-P.y)-(B.x-P.x)*(A.y-P.y);
        var planeBC:Number = (B.x-P.x)*(C.y-P.y)-(C.x - P.x)*(B.y-P.y);
        var planeCA:Number = (C.x-P.x)*(A.y-P.y)-(A.x - P.x)*(C.y-P.y);
        return sign(planeAB)==sign(planeBC) && sign(planeBC)==sign(planeCA);
    }
private function sign(n:Number):int {
        return Math.abs(n)/n;
    }
```

Removing the toys from the triangle should be pretty straight forward depending on the method you want to use.  I added a toyArray that you can iterate through to remove them.

Comment: I thought about it too, but for some reason I can't move the "already drawn triangle" (using moveTo(370, 65)). Even so, my main point is to have toys visualy inside the triangle. http://www.imghost.in/img/2016-07/07/36jx73bfm97tvrlp3ex62kn0w.jpg Simplified preview of what I want

Comment: Yes, using simple triangle.y and triangle.x DID move the shape. Please see linked image to get hang of what I need in the very end.

Comment: The number of toys will be extracted from an input textfield. And there's a bunch of math too, but that's none of concern. I need just ANY number of toys for now :)

Comment: Ok I was thinking now about a work around but if there are many toys, we better find something solid. I'm working on it

Comment: Does it matter if the toys are bunched up more densely in the corners? Or in the center?

Comment: They're supposed to be randomly placed all over the triangle. They can, however, be sorta bunched up in various places. Not TOO densely tho.

Comment: Ok. I'd suggest, then using a check, before adding the toy, to see if the randomly generated x and y coords are in the triangle, and if they aren't, retry with new random x and y coords until there is a match, then add the toy.

Comment: The only thing left to do is solve how to check if it is in the triangle.

Comment: I've googled alot before posting here, and found this, althought didn't manage to get it rolling' in my case: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/06/18/algorithm-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-triangle-with-mathematics-no-hit-test-involved/

Comment: I'll try to work it out for your case if I have time today but I gotta go for now

Comment: Yes, I've seen that example too. Ill try to find a way around this problem. 
Trying to stack up a couple of rectangles, forming a "pyramid", then add "toys" equally in each of them.

Comment: that is essentially the workaround I was thinking of. Another thing to look at if you don't want to try to figure out the triangle point test is you use a matrix transform. Another workaround would be to pix an x value at random, then the closer the x value is to the center value, the wider the y value range can be ( but this will bunch them up in the corners.

Comment: Just want to chime in here and clarify that `addChild` does NOT change the child's x/y position to `0`.   Though if you haven't set a value for the child's x/y that will be the default.

Comment: I tried to use the link you supplied to your case. See if that works.

Comment: That'll have to wait for tomorrow, got a night shift. I'll post once I implement and test Your version above. Looks neat, might be the right solution.

Comment: I just tried it. It works like a charm. You'll need to do something about the toys overlapping the edge of the triangle, probably. I'd just use a smaller triangle to put the toys in than what is actually shown.

Comment: True, the cords given are smaller then the actual field they're supposed to cover, so it's fine. Now I'm gonna do some scheming with the quantity and toys not being too close to each other. The "pyramid" way can probably make things easier, so I'll try both methods. Thanks a bunch for the help! It DOES work like a charm! :)